# jasmine-node is not working on windows

Tags: node.js, jasmine-node

I am running jasmine-node test on windows. I have following command in my package.json.

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/jasmine-node --coffee sample_spec.coffee",
  }
```

when I run npm test, I am getting following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Documents and Settings\rohan\RubymineProjects\Node
Demo\node_modules\jasmine-node\lib\jasmine-node\index.js:24:57)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Documents and Settings\rohan\RubymineProjects\Node
Demo\node_modules\jasmine-node\lib\jasmine-node\cli.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: If you run the command `./node_modules/.bin/jasmine-node --coffee sample_spec.coffee` in Windows command prompt, does it work? Have you installed `jasmine-node` globally? Are your `specs` inside a `spec/` directory?

Comment: By me it returns the same error after updating nodejs, and calling an `npm update -g`.

Comment: @RodrigoMedeiros `./node_modules/.bin/jasmine-node` returns the same error.

Comment: `npm update jasmine-node -g` solved the problem by me.

Comment: Jasmine2 appears to support nodejs, so I guess we don't need jasmine-node anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best way to solve the issue, but I installed cygwin and just ran all of my jasmine commands through that. Makes life easier when using modules like jasmine through the command line in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

So after spend of hours working on it, i found reason and solution
https://github.com/json5/json5/issues/4#issuecomment-5967750

We have to update npm on our windows :)